# NameError: global name 'full_url' is not defined

Tags: python

I tried to use global but then it gives me Global NameError Not Defined.
 It fails on the error:
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'full_url' referenced before assignment

```
env = sys.argv[1]
class Account:
    def __init__(self):

        self.stag_url       =   'http:url_1'
        self.prod_url       =   'http://url_2'

        self.account_number =   'XXXXXXX'
        self.api_url        =   "ZZZZZZ"
        self.headers        =   { "Client": "ZZZZ", \
                                  "content-type": "application/json", \
                                  "Accept": "application/json;v=2" }

        def request_data(self,env):
        if env == "staging":
            full_url = self.stag_url + self.account_number + self.api_url
        if env == "prod":
            full_url = self.prod_url + self.account_number + self.api_url

        print("URL: " + full_url + '\n')

        try:
            req   = requests.get(full_url,headers=self.headers)
            return req.status_code, req.json()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            print("Got an HTTPError: ", e.message)

acnt = Account()

if sys.argv[2] == "response_code":
    status_code,response_json = acnt.request_data(env)
    print("Response Code: " + str(status_code))
    print('\n' + "Response JSON Body: " + '\n')
    print(json.dumps(response_json, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

if sys.argv[2] == "response_json":
    status_code,response_json = acnt.request_data(env)
    print(json.dumps(response_json, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Comment: most likely your variable `env` isn't set. You should also fix your indention so your code is readable

Comment: env is already set above the class itself.

Comment: And what is the value of env? is it possible that neither the first if ("staging") nor the second ("prod") match so that `full_url` is not defined when you print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to work backwards from the error message. In the line

```
print("URL: " + full_url + '\n')
```

`full_url` is a local variable, but has not been set yet. Where can it be set? Well, only in the lines above:

```
if env == "staging":
    full_url = ..something
if env == "prod":
    full_url = ..something
```

It follows that `env` is neither `"staging"` nor `"prod"`. You can make sure by modifying the above code to

```
if env == "staging":
    full_url = ..something
elif env == "prod":
    full_url = ..something
else:
    assert False, 'env must be one of staging, production'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're env is not one of `staging` or `prod` this will fail as `full_url` will not be set when the print executes. Change it to an if, elif, else:

```
if env == "staging":
    full_url = self.stag_url + self.account_number + self.api_url
elif env == "prod":
    full_url = self.prod_url + self.account_number + self.api_url
else:
    raise Exception("Unsupported ENV")
```

Also it may be worth setting the ENV on the Account class itself as an instance var. This will avoid having to use globals.

Comment: OMG!!!! thank you @tknickman.. u saved me.. I was passing `stag` instead of `staging`

Comment: Happy to help @beginner_world